# How do you join tables using a DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Imagine I have a "**Records**" table, with "RecordID, UserID".

Then, I have a "**Users**" table, with "UserID, Username".

Next, I have a DataGridView that shows data in the Records table. All I see are numbers (1, 3... etc.) But instead, I want it to show **RecordID and Username**.

For example:

```
SELECT r.RecordID, u.Username
FROM Records r, Users u
WHERE r.UserID = u.UserID
```

Similarly, I need it to be able to update, so someone can type a Username into this DataGridView, which will insert the appropriate RecordID and UserID into the Records table.

How could this be done?

Comment: are you familiar with how to use a `JOIN` statement in SQL..? do a google search also here is a good tutorial on DataGridView http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-tutorial.htm

Comment: I am, yes, however I was brought up using "WHERE" to join tables, so I do that when it's an option. I know how to use JOIN, but even though I can write the SQL, I don't know how to apply that to DataGridView. I haven't found any place to write SQL.

Comment: you do not write the SQL to the DataGridView.. you need a `SqlDataAdapter` for example look at that link I sent it has great examples on how to bind your data to the datagridview here is the section you want to look at http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-sql-server.htm

Answer (score 0):

It depends... would you please provide more information about the DataTypes you are using in your `DataBind` property for your DataGrid?

For example, if you are using `DataTable`, you could use the `DataTable.Merge`. Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But you have to be sure you are dealing with the same table structures.